# ListBox axpx.net sort property Devexpress vol 2011.2.11

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to sort items in ListBox in aspx.net. I'm binding Datasource to my list box. All I need to know is there any apportunity to sort items in listbox? If it is, please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort your datasource before binding to the listbox

Comment: thanks, but I was interested if there was a default property in list box. So you say, that List box as it is has no such property? and what about SortOrder Property? can it be used in this case?

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_SortOrdertopic

Comment: And what about this property? Can I use it in vol 2011.2.11

Comment: If the list box control is associated with a data source (functions in bound mode), setting the SortOrder property will have no effect. Look at [this page](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_SortOrdertopic)

Comment: ok, thank you Charlie! I knew about it, but supposed that in new volume it's different a bit